# How do I programmatically generate a data.frame from many Shiny inputs?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny application that has ~100 user inputs, some of which may go untouched. I think that I could make a reactive dataframe within the app by writing `input$user_input_1`, `input$user_input_2`, etc. 100 times to call each input individually. Instead, I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically generate that list of inputs using a concatenating function and then evaluate those inputs as if I had typed `input$user_input_1`. When I run the following code, however, I get a message telling me that `Error: object 'input' not found`.

My end goal is to be able to take these user inputs and use them in some behind-the-scenes transformations. If my current set up isn't the most efficient way to capture a large number of inputs, please let me know, but at the very least I'd like to understand what isn't working here.

I'd appreciate some help here. Thanks.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

input_tbl <- tibble(inputs = c("x", "y", "z"))

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(
                inputId = "number_x",
                label   = "Input X",
                value   = 30
            ),
            numericInput(
                inputId = "number_y",
                label   = "Input Y",
                value   = 60
            ),
            numericInput(
                inputId = "number_z",
                label   = "Input Z",
                value   = 90
            )
        ),

        mainPanel(
           verbatimTextOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    value_tbl <- eventReactive(
        eventExpr = input$number_x,
        valueExpr = {

            tibble(
              inputs = input_tbl %>% pull(),
              values = input_tbl %>%
                  pull() %>%
                  modify(~ str_c("input$number_", .x)) %>%
                  map(~ parse(text = .x)) %>%
                  map(eval)
            )

        })

    output$table <- renderPrint(value_tbl())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you could achieve your desired result with `purrr::map_df` in one line of code like so:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  value_tbl <- eventReactive(
    eventExpr = input$number_x,
    valueExpr = {
      map_df(input_tbl$inputs, ~ data.frame(inputs = .x, values = input[[paste0("number_", .x)]]))
    })
  
  output$table <- renderPrint(value_tbl())
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a far more elegant solution than my own. Thank you, stefan.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong evaluation function.

Instead of `map(eval)`, I need to use `map(eval.parent)`.